# Change a background image with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I would like to change the background of the website. The problem is that I have almost zero experience on Greasemonkey. I have this script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Tamo
// @namespace   TamoImageChanger
// @include     https://sistema.tamo.lt*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var x = 0;
while (x < images.length) {
    if (images[x].src == "https://sistema.tamo.lt/Content/img/new/login_background2.jpg") {
        images[x].src = "the image i want to be displayed";
    }
    x = x + 1;
}
```

but it works only when I am in this webpage:
      https://sistema.tamo.lt/Content/img/new/login_background2.jpg

I want the script to change the background in this webpage though:
      https://sistema.tamo.lt/Prisijungimas/Login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you're trying to visit is displaying this image as a background image and not a image tag.

And this script actually change the source of all `<img/>` tags.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

So I did customize your script to accomplish whatever you want to do. To make this more educative, I gonna explain step by step what happen.

```
// Here I'm retrieving the tag displaying the picture by specifying exact path.
var image = document.querySelector("body > .container_2 > .col_left");

// Here I just change the background image by yours.
image.style.backgroundImage = "url('INSERT YOUR IMAGE')";
```

-

**EDIT**

As [Brock Adams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/331508/brock-adams) mentionned below, you can also accomplish the same work as above, GreaseMonkey style.

```
GM_addStyle("div[style*='login_background2.jpg'] {background-image: url('INSERT YOUR IMAGE')!important;} ")
```

Comment: Good enough. Or just use [`GM_addStyle()`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle), or [the Stylish add-on](https://userstyles.org/) to add a CSS rule like: `div[style*='login_background2.jpg'] {background-image: url('INSERT YOUR IMAGE')!important;}` .

Comment: Well, that's an interesting comment. It's been awhile I didn't used GM so I've been with an answer I'm sure about the result. I gonna edit my answer with GM_addStyle as it's a drop in solution. Thanks !

Comment: Thank you! This script works perfectly!

Comment: Another alternative is to use the Stylish addon for your browser. It adds whatever css you want to the indicated page (no javascript)... Browser specific links can be found on https://userstyles.org/.